# how do you obtain the soul echo device?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

I've been looking for the item "soul echo device" it's been suggested to me that it is obtained through a Dragonball wish but I wasn't told which one. how do I obtain the soul echo device?

Answer (score 2):

They can be obtained from one of Shenron's wishes, the "I want to be stronger!" wish

> **I want to get stronger!** – Provides 6 Echo Soul Devices which can be mixed with Super Souls to create even more powerful souls.

Source: [Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2 Guide: How to Pick Shenron’s Wishes](https://twinfinite.net/2016/10/dragon-ball-xenoverse-2-guide-how-to-pick-shenrons-wishes/2/)

Comment: thank you. do you know if this wish can be done several times?

Comment: @Catofdoom2 [Reply 4 on this GameFAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/190457-dragon-ball-xenoverse-2/74574281) says *"You can only obtain them through Shenron Wishes **each wish gives you 6 of those** ."* which to me sounds like it can be done over and over again however i have not played the game to know for sure if this is the case or not